# Raspbian Stretch doesn't show any display on boot

Tags: raspbian-stretch, hdmi, gui

I installed the image of raspbian stretch (version: 9) on an SD card and mounted the card on the Raspberry Pi. On first boot the display came up and the initial setup was done. In addition to the initial setup I configured the pi for SSH connection (save WiFi Credentials, static IP).

The next time I switched ON the raspberry there was no display, but I was able to access the pi over SSH. Over SSH I accessed the RPI config and changed the boot options.
[image: First Screen of RPI config][[image: Second Screen]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRMoe.png)[[image: Third screen]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhm3W.png)

When I do this and reboot the Pi, it boots to the GUI but on another reboot the GUI does not come up.

One of two things happen when I reboot the Pi,

1. There is no input to the monitor. (Monitor is Idle)
2. There is an input to the monitor, but only a black screen

Raspberry pi model: 2

Connected to monitor via HDMI to VGA adapter

Power Supply: 5V 2A

The Pi does not boot to the CLI either.

Comment: Which model Pi? What monitor & resolution? Connected by HDMI? What power supply?

Comment: Updated the details to the question